# Can't run Protractor with Safari

Tags: angularjs, safari, automated-tests, protractor, safaridriver

I'm trying to solve it for days, please help me!

I'm running my protractor tests using chrome, firefox and internet explorer, but when I try to run the same test in Safari, I get the following error:

```
    ScriptTimeoutError: Timed out awaiting response to command "executeScript" after 30003 ms (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.08 seconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'myPC', ip: '192.168.0.12', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=5.1.7, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, platform=WINDOWS, secureSsl=true}]
Session ID: null
```

The error comes when I try to get some url like `browser.get('https://www.google.com');` I tried to run the same test in Safari in my colleague's macbook to see if the problem is my windows environment (and the older safari version 5.1.7) but had the same problem. I also tried to change the `allScriptsTimeout` and got the same problem, I tried many different configurations in my protractor configuration file and it didn't worked =(

I'm sure that I"m doing something wrong but have no ideia about what... I didn't found more information about this error.

Edit: There is a known issue (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2111) about using protractor with safari